# Custom Login to WooCommerce Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom login form on header

```
<form method="post" action="http://pwhs.ph.local/wp-login.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password" />
    '.wp_nonce_field( 'login-nonce' ).'
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="login" value="Login" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="register" value="Register" />
    <a id="lost-password" href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/my-account/lost-password/' ) ).'">Lost your password?</a>
</form>
```

It login the user but it directs to WP Dashboard, it should login the user to WooCommerce. I can direct the data to the form-login.php of WooCommerce but how can I login it instead of showing the login form of  WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of custom form code, I will suggest you to use plugin e.g. Theme My Login, 
Use its shortcode in your them header file so it will display login page and in admin settings set the redirection after login. 
Please refer following links:

[Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)

[TML Shortcodes](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/)

Comment: there should be no login page it should be directly from the field on the header

Answer (score 0):

```
**add_action( 'init', 'redirect_users_init' );
function redirect_users_init() {
if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
}
}**
```

here instead of home_url() you can put the url you need

or you can use this plugin also https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-dashboard/